# Java - ArrayList remove() not working [passing String]

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm having some trouble with removing an item from an ArrayList, specifically removing an item which has been specified and passing the id of this item to the remove() function.

```
    DockService service = new DockServiceImpl();
    // This should remove the boat with the ID: NV 2345 KO
    service.removeBoat("NV 2345 KO");

    if (service.getDock().getDockedBoats().size() == 2) {
        System.out.println("Test 2 - Removing a boat: Passed.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Test 2 - Removing a boat: Failed.");
    }
```

This is the ArrayList in a separate class

```
    public static List<Boat> createBoatList() {
    List<Boat> boatList = new ArrayList<>();

    Boat firstBoat = new Boat("NV 1234 VN", 1000);
    Boat secondBoat = new Boat("NV 2345 KO", 1500);
    Boat thirdBoat = new Boat("NV 3053 NZ", 2000);

    boatList.add(firstBoat);
    boatList.add(secondBoat);
    boatList.add(thirdBoat);

    return boatList;
}
```

This is the dock class which contains the get set methods

```
  public Dock(String name, int capacity) {
    this.name = name;
    this.capacity = capacity;
    this.dockedBoats = new ArrayList<>();
}
    public List<Boat> getDockedBoats() {
    return dockedBoats;
}
```

So in my removal method, i have tried this

```
private Dock dock;
public boolean removeBoat(String boatId) {
    System.out.println(">>> Deleting boat.");
    this.dock.getDockedBoats().remove(boatId);
    return false;
}
```

But the remove(boatId) does not remove the boat from the arraylist, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You are storing `Boat` objects in your `List` - then you are trying to remove one `Boat` by passing a `String` - this will not work.  You need to first find the matching `Boat` object given the parameter and then remove that object from the list

Comment: also, your method should do -->  `return this.dock.getDockedBoats().remove(boatId);` instead of just `return false;`

Comment: After you remove the object you should have 2 left, not 3.  Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(java.lang.Object)

Comment: @TomRobertson, regardless, it is a mess.  I did not downvote btw.  I think you answer is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing `Boat` objects in your `List` - then you are trying to remove one `Boat` by passing a `String` -> this will not work.

You need to first find the matching `Boat` object given the parameter and then remove that object from the list.

Something along the lines of:

```
public boolean removeBoat(String boatId) {
    System.out.println(">>> Deleting boat.");
    Boat b = findBoatById(boatId);

    if( b != null ){
       this.dock.getDockedBoats().remove(b);
       return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public Boat findBoatById(String boatId) {
    System.out.println(">>> Find boat from list.");

    for( Boat b : this.dock.getDockedBoats() ){
       if( boatId.equalsIgnoreCase( b.boatId ) ){
          return b;
       } 
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Not a downvoter. Just a question. didn't you mean .remove(b) instead of .remove(boatId) as I am not sure if equals method is overridden to match boatId.

Comment: @Jimmy youre right, works perfectly once i corrected that, thanks

Comment: Thanks @Jimmy - I fixed the typo now